# For a one-tailed test using OLS regression in SPSS, is it appropriate to divide the change statistics p-values in half?

Tags: r-squared

I am running a series of moderation regression models in SPSS and entering the models in using blocking (e.g., controls in block 1, controls and IVs in block 2, controls, IVs and moderator in block 3).  My predictions call for a one-tailed test, which I know requires dividing the beta coefficient p-values in half.

My question is that when I am looking at the change in R-square F change significance, do I also divide that value in half?  Specifically, in my model, the second block as an R-square F change significance of .001 and the third model (the one with the interaction) has an R-square F change significance of .072.  Do I divide that in half to be .036?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Nope. F-tests are always 1 tailed tests. The F distribution has only one tail (to the right). F distributions are t distibutions that can have more than 1 df. The critical value for the two tailed t-test is equivalent to the critical value for the F-test with 1 df.

The 1 tail vs 2 tail issue is irrelevant in an F test because, for example, if you find a significant F comparing 3 groups in a one-way ANOVA, you do not know which group was higher than which. All you know is that the the groups "differed."

What is your hypothesis specifically?

Comment: Correct, one only looks at one tail of the $F$ distribution, but what $F$ is testing is non-directional so could be called a 2-tailed hypothesis.  But as @Hotaka said it is not correct to halve its p-value because of the complexity of what it is testing.